# How to Download MS 932 Text File Encoding for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run a java file in eclipse, but it has some essential Japanese characters in order to run. I went to Window->Preferences->Text File Encoding->Other, but there is no MS 932 listed. How can I get this library to Eclipse. I tried checking online, of course, but nothing. I tried switching to UTF-8, but still does not work.

Comment: Switch the file to UTF8.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work

Comment: I think the `javac -encoding Cp932` might work.

Answer (score 0):

The encodings might be restricted; try maybe SJIS too.

```
native2ascii -reverse -encoding MS932 My.java temp.txt
... rename My.Java
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 temp.txt My.java
```